# Initializing Java File object in Clojure always gives relative path in Windows. How do I give it absolute path?

Tags: java, file, clojure

Here's some Clojure code :

```
(defn test [path]
(let [jp (.replace path "\\" "/")
      p (-> jp io/file .getAbsolutePath)]
  (println "Initial argument:: " path)
  (println "Java-ized string " jp)
  (println "The File object absolute path " p)
      MORE STUFF
  ))
```

And when called with path as "C:\Users\Eletro"

I get this output

```
Initial argument::  C:\Users\Eletro
Java-ized string  C:/Users/Eletro
The File object absolute path  /mnt/c/Users/Eletro/Documents/Repos/winfsq/C:/Users/Eletro
```

In other words, I'm sending it what looks like an absolute path, starting with "C:\"

I replace the backslashes with slashes to make it Java.

But when I create the File object, and ask what the absolute path is, I see that my path has been added as relative to where the code running.

Why?

And how do I get the File constructor to treat it as an absolute path?

Note that I'm running the Clojure compiler and this program from inside Ubuntu for Windows layer

Comment: Something to try would be `getCanonicalPath` instead of `getAbsolutePath`

Comment: But surely this shouldn't depend on how you access the data once it's IN the File object? I mean, I want the File object to contain the right file / directory from the beginning.

Comment: I tried your suggestion anyway, but it's the same

Comment: If you run the JVM in a linux-like environment, don't be surprised if it expects linux-like paths instead of windows paths. `C:/Users/Eletro` is a perfectly valid relative path on linux: how else could you possibly specify such a path, if the JVM interpreted this as absolute for some reason?

Comment: That's a good point, so how can I force File to treat it as absolute?

Comment: Pass it an absolute path on the filesystem it's actually using: `/mnt/c/...` instead of `C:/...`.

Comment: But the point is I'm developing in WSL but I want to run it on the ordinary windows file system. That is what I'm trying to test ... how it runs in "normal windows". I just want to do the development in WSL.